# BIND9 priority for host failover

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, bind

I'm wondering if it's possible to have a host assigned to several ip addresses:

```
MediaGrid       IN      A       192.168.0.1
                IN      A       192.168.0.2
                IN      A       192.168.0.3
                IN      A       192.168.0.4
```

and if said host don't answer, lookup for the next ip listed. I have some notions about rrset-order but I think it would only served as a sort of load balancing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Multiple `A`ddress records (indeed, multiples of **any** type of record) in DNS are interpreted as a ["Round Robin"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS) situation., and there's generally no way of guaranteeing a particular order or rotating through the addresses - whichever IP your resolver picks for you is the one that will be used.

You *may* implement a hunt-group in your own code (do the DNS lookup, collect all the addresses, and hunt through them yourself), but stock DNS and standard resolvers won't do this for you, so you can't use this as a failover scheme for a website (as an example).

---

If you want proper fail-over what you really want is a load balancer (or a redundant pair of them sharing a single virtual IP) that ensure that the back-end hosts are up and working properly before sending requests to them.  That's way beyond the scope of DNS though.